# SQL question on indexes. How to call the index that I have created

Tags: sql, indexing, rdbms

How can I call the indexes that I have created for a table in SQL?

For example I have created an index:

`CREATE INDEX idx_pname ON Persons (LastName, FirstName);`

How can I call it?

Comment: You don't call it. The database will use it if the engine thinks it will help.

Comment: Depending on which database flavor you're using, you might be able to add a *hint* to a query to tell the SQL Optimizer that it should use the index, but that is generally not needed, since the SQL Optimizer is pretty smart. --- Also depending on which database flavor you're using, you can ask the database engine to show you how it intends to execute the query, including which indexes will be used, if any. This is generally called *Explain Plan* or *Analyze SQL* or something like that, depending on database flavor and/or tools used to do it.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thanks, I have added rdbms tag

Comment: Did you read the link from a_horse_with_name? It doesn't say to add the 'rdbms' tag, it says to add the tag for the DBMS you are using. [ask] [mre] [help] PS This shows no research effort.

Comment: I have added "edbms" tag. I think its more directive than "dbms"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are background data structures, which you cannot call directly. They will be internally used by the query, for getting data, if it finds the index to be good way to get the data in the optimal manner.

If you want to force the query optimizer to leverage an index, you can use index hint. Below is an example.

```sql
SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Persons WITH (INDEX = idx_pname )
```

But, I would always suggest not to use index hint, as it can bring in lots of issues.

- When the statistics change also, forcing an index will lead to performance issues
- If the index is dropped, the query will not work

But, if you want to see what indexes are present on a table, you can use `sp_help` to see the table information.

```sql
EXEC sp_help 'dbo.Persons'
```

Also, you can use `sp_helpindex`

```sql
EXEC sp_helpindex 'dbo.Persons'
```

[More on sp_helpindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helpindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @tallamtharunsai, if it answers your question, please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future

Comment: sure. I will do it.

Comment: sure. Have a nice day Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. I have understood it. So, basically the database uses indexes if they fell they are required to call. This in order useful for query search optimization. We will simply create an index if we feel that this is called more or it is will be used more frequently.

Comment: It have really helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Indexes defined on fields belonging to database table are part of database schema and indexes are defined with purpose to speed up performance of data retrieval operations from database tables as indexed fields are looked up into specific sort order according to index definition and speeds up process as search stops once matched record is found. So as a part of query execution plan indexes are applied according to select query definition.

To determine whether indexes are used into select operation explain statement is used

```
EXPLAIN SELECT statement
```